# Can someone help me understand why my PHP css stylesheet is not working suddenly?

Tags: php, debugging, stylesheet

I built a CSS as normal for a website. I then read that you can re-name the CSS as a PHP page with the proviso that `<?php header("Content-type: text/css"); ?>` is put on line one of the PHP page.

Then rather than linking to the 'style.css' you can link instead to 'style.php' and no worries.

When I did this, everything was working perfectly fine, flawlessly.  Before anyone asks why I did it, I will explain.  I also created a basic CSS tool to change various colors and fonts through a HTML forms blah, blah blah.  Everything was working okej..... then POOF!

Now the CSS is only loading partially and I have a bit of code that popped up.

The syntax that I am using to link to the PHP CSS is:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="phpstylesheet.php">
```

the errant code that appears at the very top of the page is a fragment of the stylesheet link:

```
' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

I haven't the foggiest clue what went wrong all of a sudden.

Can anyone diagnose what I did to suddenly screw this up?

Comment: What kind of code does the PHP CSS file contain?

Comment: sounds like the problem is with your PHP/HTML, not the style script. Can you show the code that generates the `<head>` of the page?

Comment: Must have been something you recently changed. What editor are you using?

Comment: the fragment that is being shown makes me think you might have unmatched quotation marks somewhere in there. -- Needs more code to diagnose fully.

Comment: one little thing to check is that `Content-Type:` may be case-sensitive, although that doesn't look like it's the primary issue

Comment: Thanks to all. I found the problem as described under the answer. DaveRandom: It really was an issue with my HTML/PHP, you got that right on. Sabre, you also had it right to a degree, it was funny echoing not of quotation marks, but rather forward slashes that were causing problems. I appraciate everyones suggestions and help, I really dig this forum and service!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a error that breaks your document since you say the styles are partially loading. Try putting the code below at the very top of your document and you should see which errors are generated.

```
<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ?>
```

Your server settings does problably not allow you to see errors. You can read more about error handling here: http://php.net/manual/en/book.errorfunc.php

Just remember to remove the line above again when commiting your file to production environment.

Comment: Thank you to all for your ideas and input!  As it turns out, it was an issue I was having with my echoing syntax, not within the PHP CSS link, as I suspected, but rather, in the link I was achoing to google web fonts actually.  I had a CSS tool/form in which I could replace or update the link to Google Web fonts, BUT.... I was echoing the entire URL.  The forward slashes in the echo were goofing things up it apears.  So now, rather than echo the entire URL I am just eching the information AFTER "http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?"  apears to be working now Thanks!